# Does Isaiah 44:6 present a contradiction with respect to the nature of God, the Father and his Son?

Tags: jesus, contradiction, isaiah, christology, attributes-of-god

It seems as though much of the evidence in the OT for God having a Son, is fairly ambiguous, such as

> 7 I will proclaim the Lord’s decree:
> He said to me, “You are my son; today I have become your father. 8 Ask me, and I will make the nations your inheritance, the ends of the earth your possession. (Psalm 2:7-8).

This is a Messianic Psalm that could be referring to the coming Messiah designated as the Son of God. So, for me, one of the strongest verses in the OT referring to the preexistence of Jesus (the Word) is Isaiah 44:6:

> “Thus says the LORD, the King of Israel and his Redeemer, the LORD of hosts:
> ‘I am the first and I am the last,
> And there is no God besides Me.

If the Redeemer refers to the pre-existent Word, God's Son, wouldn't the second half of the verse seem to be a contradiction? Otherwise how do you interpret the verse hermeneutically?

Answer (score 3):

Does the Tanakh claim Elohim YHVH has a supernatural anointed son who is both God over all (Romans 9:5) & has a Father in heaven (Matthew 6:9)?

> [Isaiah 44:6]
> So said YHVH, ( כֹּֽה־אָמַ֨ר יְהֹוָ֧ה )
> the King of Yisrael ( מֶֽלֶךְ־יִשְׂרָאֵ֛ל )
> and his-Redeemer ( וְגֹֽאֲל֖וֹ )

- Notice : YHVH is declaring Himself only as both King & Redeemer of Yisrael.

> YHVH of Hosts, ( יְהֹוָ֣ה צְבָא֑וֹת )
> "I am [the] First" ( אֲנִ֚י רִאשׁוֹן֙ )

- YHVH has no Father, because He is the First.

> and I am [the] Last, ( וַֽאֲנִ֣י אַֽחֲר֔וֹן )

- YHVH has no heavenly brother, sister, or equal. He is the Last. - No other Diety has existed in this universe.

> and besides Me ( וּמִבַּלְעָדַ֖י )

***...wait for it...***

> there is no God." ( אֵ֥ין אֱלֹהִֽים )

**But my KJV & NIV Bible says Jesus the Nazarene is both God over all (Romans 9:5) & has a Father in heaven (Matthew 6:9) ?** - These New Testament concepts contradict YHVH in Isaiah 44:6. - ** Why did YHVH never mention another Diety Son that existed before the creation of the world who through righteousness would be allowed to sit on the metaphorical throne of YHVH ? --- Because [1 Enoch] had not been written yet.**

Although my own KJV & NIV Bible denies the inclusion of 1 Enoch, the concept of YHVH having another anointed Son-God in Heaven (prior to earth's existence) who rules over the world in place of YHVH is all from 1 Enoch.

- Jude 1:14-15 was quoting 1 Enoch 1:9.
- Mark 14:21 references 1 Enoch 38:2.
- 1 Peter 1:20 was quoting 1 Enoch 48:6.
- John 5:22 references 1 Enoch 69:27.

**The Torah & Tanakh do not share the theological concepts of 1 Enoch & New Testament.**

**YHVH (speaking through the prophet Yeshayahu "Isaiah") clearly reveals Himself and His Title and His Status in Yeshayahu יְשַׁעְיָ֣הוּ "Isaiah" 44:6**

Comment: I am upvoting this because it provides good information. I would still like to hear more from you or others about the general reticence in the Tanakh to plainly reveal the existence of the Son.  Apparently I will have to modify the question to try to get it reopened.

Comment: Enoch was already written but supposing you’re right that it wasn’t, Psalm 2:7 was and Proverbs 30:4 was certainly written. Isaiah 48:16 was, and we have God sending God and God’s Spirit. That’s three persons being identified.

Comment: I will incorporate Isa. 44:6 into my question. Great verse!